Generate hex file from "c" program using riscv compiler , rodata must be aligned by 4 bytes
i want to generate hex file , that contains rodata as aligned 4 bytes . But my riscv compiler generate  hex file ,that contains rodata as aligned 2 bytes. i have tried many methods
1.i have already tried  ALIGN concepts in my linker.ld
2.im analysis my riscv compiler and find  .lds files , i altered these files but no use there is no change in compilers behavior
in my c program, if rodata is 2 byte or lessthan 2 byte
  rodata = {4444,0022}

ex :
00  : 4444
02  : 0000
04  : 0022
06  : 0000
in my c program ,if rodata is higher than two bytes
rodata = {ffff4444,00048888}
type here

ex :
00 : 4444
02 : ffff
04 : 8888
06 : 0004
this is my compilers behaviors , is there any option to generate hex that contains rodata as aligned 4 bytes ?
my expected output
00 : 00004444
04 : 00000022
please give me some idea, thankyou

It's not clear to me what the issue you have is. In both cases each value in rodata has a size of 4 bytes, and is shown as being aligned at a 4-byte boundary. It's just a difference in how it's being printed, as 16-bit numbers, instead of 32-bit numbers. The size of the elements of rodata doesn't change just because you change the size of the numbers.

What is rodata? Is it linker section name or actual C variable name? If latter, what is the type of it?

rodata = {4444,0022} looks unlikely to me as C syntax and the details matter.
for example:
uint16_t rodata = { 0x4455, 0x0022}; should produce on little-endian target platform stream of bytes (in hexa): 55 44 22 00
while uint32_t rodata = { 0x4455, 0x0022}; will produce stream of bytes 55 44 00 00 22 00 00 00.
How you display the resulting binary in hex file (per two bytes or per four bytes) doesn't matter, that's just formatting for display, you can display same data in different way. Focus on the bytes and their content and what you want to achieve on binary level.

or if the hex file formatting matters, then explain why/how, some tool processing the hex file has issues with per-two-byte formatting? But then that's not related to programming, that's just tooling/file format issue and would require from you to describe which tools and versions are being used and what exactly is happening, as in general way none of this should matter or cause any issue.
